# Ubuntu: how to look up source code for a utility?

Tags: c, ubuntu

How do I look up the source code for a utility which has a different name from its parent package?

For example, I would like to look up:
`/usr/bin/sort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run

dpkg -S /usr/bin/sort

to get name of package, then see package info, get url go to its site and get source code.

Answer (score 4):

The `apt-get source` command will download the Ubuntu packaging and source for you:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/sort
coreutils: /usr/bin/sort
$ cd /tmp
$ apt-get source coreutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 10.8 MB of source archives.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main coreutils 8.5-1ubuntu6 (dsc) [1,955 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main coreutils 8.5-1ubuntu6 (tar) [10.7 MB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main coreutils 8.5-1ubuntu6 (diff) [23.3 kB]
Fetched 10.8 MB in 6s (1,731 kB/s)                                                   
dpkg-source: info: extracting coreutils in coreutils-8.5
dpkg-source: info: unpacking coreutils_8.5.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6.diff.gz
$
```

Now the `coreutils-8.5` directory contains the patched sources, ready for rebuilding with `debuild(1)`, and the `coreutils_8.5.orig.tar.gz` contains the original upstream source, if you want to work with that instead of the the patched sources.

Answer (score 3):

Run the program with `--version` or `--help` or read the man page credits or copyright statement and you may find out that it's a GNU project utility. In any case, it will give you enough search terms to locate it. (You can find the man page on line even if you aren't running the OS nearby.)

In the case of your `/usr/bin/sort` example, this would prompt a search for *"gnu coreutils"* which will return [**this gnu site**](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) as the top result.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can find the package from which a given program came using dpkg -S, as in `dpkg -S /usr/bin/sort`.